# I'm not able to set a video in the activity

Tags: android, video

Hello I wish not to disturb but I'm newer to developing program.

I'm trying to make a video playing in an activity but I get always black screen.

My video is in mp4 h264 created with ffmpeg with android profile and plays in quicktime and is set in res/raw/corsolex_1.mp4

I attach the code I'm writing to understand what I miss to do, if someone can help I'm very grateful.

Angelo

**this activity is called Clipvideo1**

```
package com.wocmultimedia.VideoEditLesson1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Clipvideo1 extends Activity {@Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.clip1);

// Put the media file into the res/raw folder of your application
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.corsolex_1);
mp.start();
}}
```

**this is the XML layout called clip1.xml**

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <VideoView android:id="@+id/videoView1" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></VideoView>

    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't link the video to VideoView somehow.

So as you see you have 3 parts of the uri:

1. "android.resource://"
2. "com.wocmultimedia.VideoEditLesson1"
3. your resource

"corsolex_1" is the name of your video

Maybe this code helps:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.clip1);

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

    Uri videoPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.corsolex_1);

    videoView.setVideoURI(videoPath);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very very much eventually I'm understanding a little bit more...i'm very sorry but i'm at very beginning with this job so i get confused soon and mixed the things...i will try your solution and let you know the result...thanks a lot again.

Comment: I'm sorry but I got lost again can you say in simple words if and where I've to change something cause I copied your code in my project and get an URI error. Be patient, please check this error cause I cannot add the screen shot here and help me to understand how to set it correct.  "The method setVideoUri(Uri) is undefined for the type VideoView" it appears in the line  "videoView.setVideoUri(videoPath);" Thanks a lot! Angelo

Comment: @evilone I'm sorry but I got lost again can you say in simple words if and where I've to change something cause I copied your code in my project and get an URI error. Be patient, please check this error cause I cannot add the screen shot here and help me to understand how to set it correct. "The method setVideoUri(Uri) is undefined for the type VideoView" it appears in the line "videoView.setVideoUri(videoPath);" Thanks a lot! Angelo

Comment: @Angelo Giammarresi Do you have a real device to test with? Because it doesn't work on my emulator, but on the real device this code wa ok. Also please check that all code is correct for your project.

Comment: @evilone sorry but i haven't a real device. can you say me where i can send you a screen shot to show you my project? thank you very much you can use my mail wocmultimedia@ymail.com

Comment: No need for screenshot, whats the value of Uri string?

Comment: @evilone package com.wocmultimedia.VideoEditLesson1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class Clipvideo1 extends Activity {@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 // TODO...
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.clip1);
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

Uri videoPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.corsolex_1);

videoView.setVideoUri(videoPath);
videoView.requestFocus();
videoView.start();
}
}

Comment: Does the corsolex_1 resource exists in the raw folder of the project?

Comment: yes! in the res/raw/corsolex_1.mp4 the error I get is in the "videoView.setVideoUri(videoPath);" I get the red dot with X saying "The method setVideoUri(Uri) is undefined for the type VideoView" so I cannot run the application

Comment: do not use setVideoUri then, use setVideoURI instead. Method names in Java are case sensitive!

Comment: It works, the error sign disappeared but when I run it I can only listen the music with blank screen, no video shown

Comment: do not use the emulator for testing video playback. Its ability to handle video playback is very limited. Use an actual Android device.

Comment: @evilone - i tested in a toshiba folio and it works, can you say me how i can add a controller, a bar to search in the video lenght? Thank you very much. Have a good day.

Comment: I think your question is answered. This is already new question and you can ask new question for that...

Answer (score 0):

[VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) is a sub-class of SurfaceView which contains and manages a MediaPlayer object. In your XML file you declare the **VideoView** and in your Java code you create and manages a **MediaPlayer** object. They are separate and there is no relation between them in your code. So you have 2 options:

1. Use the VideoView, as described in **evilone**'s answer, and let it manage the **MediaPlayer** object. **This is the best way IMHO**, someone already developed the handling of the MediaPlayer object, and wrapped it up nicely for you.
2. Use MediaPlayer, but manage it properly, including the handling and attaching of the surface and the surface holder. Look at the [MediaPlayerDemo_Video](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html) in the android developer site to see how it should be done.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, it's great from both of you and i wish i can help you if you need video editing tips. I'm just trying to write a little app to show my video-production. So, step by step i'm building it. thank you very much.